# Apple Mach-O Linker Error when using CocoaPods with Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, linker-errors

I am trying to add PFAnalytics ([instructions here](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#analytics/events/mobile/ios/native/existing)). Below is my PodFile. I just hit `pod install` and tried to compile and run, and I see the errors below:

`pod file`:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, ‘8.0’

target 'ShitTalk' do
pod ‘Parse’
end

target 'ShitTalkTests' do

end
```

I tried to add Google Analytics too and I see the same error so I think if I try with ANY library with Cocoapods, it's going to do this.

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You **must use** the `.xcworkspace` file after `pod install` instead of `.xcodeproj` file.

The `xcworkspace` contains your `project` and your `pods`.

After that you should be able to run normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two solutions

1. Remove the library `.a` file from the `ProjectTarget->Build Phase`
2. Open the workspace  `.xcworkspace` instead of opening the `.xcodeproj`

Comment: Remove ALL `.a` files? I have `.a` files from some other libraries that I think I need: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w3ls1wjbw426fal/Screenshot%202015-09-01%2023.30.47.png?dl=0